# Am I using the correct adjectives?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives

Am I using the correct adjectives and is this construction grammatically correct?

> It can also be characterized as a vertically *dominated* object.

The idea is the object that I am focusing on can also be described using its dominant shape i.e. verticality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are probably better ways to say what you are trying to say.  As @Kevin mentions, more context would be helpful to get a clearer picture, but  here are a couple of possibilities and a bit of explanation:

> It can also be characterized as a vertically dominant object

The object dominates the scene by virtue of its vertical component.

> It is a predominantly vertical object

The object's most obvious feature is that it is vertically oriented.

> It is very tall

(Nice and simple.)

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct. However, out of context, the meaning is a little unclear.  In context, it may be fine but can't say without having the surrounding text.